# can't get the response.data in node.js code but works in postman

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-docs

Im trying to fetch the google docs html file s that I later on can add my own JSON data and combine them.

I set the doc to public and everyone can edit it and when I fetch it with the api given by google it works I get the html data in the response.

I tried to set up the same logic in my node.js (express) project but I get error null in the response of postman. Any idea what Im missing?

the api of google (get):

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1us5_NdOHrbdWuVhtx8l-oNXGa7IxOWf_5JuexGJVMcw/edit
```

my code:

```
        const res = await axios.get(`https://docs.google.com/document/d/${docId}/edit`).then(response =>{
          return JSON.stringify(response.data)
        })
```

I want to receive the html document in the return, I console.log it and in the console I get the html but it only returns error in postman.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted doesn't have any bugs and seems to work fine in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cx95rnus/1/). You might be trying to console log the promise which will print null.

```
async function getHtml() {
  const docId = '1us5_NdOHrbdWuVhtx8l-oNXGa7IxOWf_5JuexGJVMcw';
  const res = await axios.get(`https://docs.google.com/document/d/${docId}/edit`).then(r => { return JSON.stringify(r.data) });
  console.log(res);
  return res
}

getHtml();
```

Comment: Tank you for the response! I do get the whole html file as a string in the console but the response on postman is :
{
    "error": null
}

Comment: @YaelTzruia, are you sending the request with an api  token, if yes set it in the postman request

Comment: it was right! I was calling it from a different function and it was an error there. Thank you!